# Show the names of executable files by pressing TAB Linux C program

Tags: c, linux, recursion, directory

I have to do a program, which in the activation of the TAB by the user searches for all executable files in the current directory and consecutive directories (if the current one contains directories).
The executable files are stored in a dynamic matrix to be later compared to the user input

My problem is that the search starts in the PATH, and for some reason whenever it tries to open the directory it gives me and error saying "No such file or directory".

```
#include "header.h"
#include <dirent.h>

char **files = NULL;
char size = 0;
char heapsize = 0;

char **tabActivation(const char *text, int start, int end);
char *filesCatch(const char *text, int state);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    char *line;
    rl_attempted_completion_function = tabActivation;

    while (1)
    {
        line = readline("msh$ ");

        if (line == NULL)
        {
            perror("malloc error!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (!strcmp(line, "exit")) exit(0);
        if (strlen(line) == 0)continue;

        add_history(line);
        CMD *root = parse_line(line);

        print_command_list(root);
        free_command_list(root);
        free(line);
    }
}

char **tabActivation(const char *text, int start, int end)
{
    rl_attempted_completion_over = 1;
    return rl_completion_matches(text, filesCatch);
}

char *filesCatch(const char *text, int state)
{
    char pwd[1024] = "", *p=NULL, *limit="/:",temp[1024]="";
    char oldpwd[1024] = "";


    files = (char **) malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
    heapsize = 10;

    strcpy(pwd, getenv("PATH"));
    strcpy(oldpwd,pwd);


    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    p = strtok(pwd,limit);
    strcat(temp,"/");
    strcat(temp,p);

    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("CURRENT DIRECTORY= %s\n",temp);

        if ((dir = opendir(temp)) == NULL)
            perror("opendir() error");
        else
        {
            puts("contents of root:");
            while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
                printf("  %s\n", entry->d_name);
            closedir(dir);
        }

        p = strtok(NULL,limit);
        strcat(temp,"/");
        strcat(temp,p);

        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

pwd(PATH) output: /home/user/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

Program Output:

```
CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home
Contents of DIRECTORY:

  .
  ..
  user


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user
Contents of DIRECTORY:

  .icons
  .dmrc
  worksheet8
  .thumbnails
  Templates
  .bashrc
  file
  .calendar
  .themes
  up-down-mutex.c
  Pictures
  ls2.txt
  main.c
  exerc1
  teste.txt
  .
  Public
  Downloads
  7-sigchld.c
  worksheet7
  project
  tmp
  Music
  run
  .Xresources
  .vboxclient-draganddrop.pid
  worksheet6
  .bash_logout
  .dbus
  Documents
  bin
  teste
  .vboxclient-clipboard.pid
  .vboxclient-seamless.pid
  .bash_aliases
  .config
  .xsessionrc
  worksheet3
  worksheet5
  .pbuilderrc
  .gtkrc-2.0.mine
  .profile
  .profile~2018-02-19T13:24:58~
  .Xauthority
  teste.c
  ls.txt
  .conkyrc
  .gconf
  .gtk-bookmarks
  .bash_history
  .xsession-errors
  .gtkrc-2.0
  worksheet1
  .vboxclient-display.pid
  .local
  worksheet4
  .lesshst
  Videos
  .cache
  .fonts
  .gmrunrc
  ..
  project.zip
  .xsession-errors.old
  worksheet2
  .mozilla
  .gksu.lock


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin
Contents of DIRECTORY:

  .
  ..


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr
opendir() error: No such file or directory


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr/sbin
opendir() error: No such file or directory


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr/sbin/sbin
opendir() error: No such file or directory


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr/sbin/sbin/usr
opendir() error: No such file or directory


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr/sbin/sbin/usr/local
opendir() error: No such file or directory


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr/sbin/sbin/usr/local/bin
opendir() error: No such file or directory


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr/sbin/sbin/usr/local/bin/usr
opendir() error: No such file or directory


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr/sbin/sbin/usr/local/bin/usr/bin
opendir() error: No such file or directory


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr/sbin/sbin/usr/local/bin/usr/bin/bin
opendir() error: No such file or directory


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr/sbin/sbin/usr/local/bin/usr/bin/bin/usr
opendir() error: No such file or directory


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr/sbin/sbin/usr/local/bin/usr/bin/bin/usr/local
opendir() error: No such file or directory


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr/sbin/sbin/usr/local/bin/usr/bin/bin/usr/local/games
opendir() error: No such file or directory


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr/sbin/sbin/usr/local/bin/usr/bin/bin/usr/local/games/usr
opendir() error: No such file or directory


CURRENT DIRECTORY= /home/user/bin/usr/sbin/sbin/usr/local/bin/usr/bin/bin/usr/local/games/usr/games
opendir() error: No such file or directory
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PATH contains multiple directories. Make sure you split the variable into multiple paths, and search each one separately.

Edit: Specifically, you could use the strtok() function, which splits the string at a specified character (The ":" in this case). You could use the function to split the PATH into separate directories.

Edit 2: Make sure to clear out the content of "temp" after every ":", as the program is currently merging the different directories in PATH, which shouldn't be merged.

Comment: After /home/user/bin the output is going to be always the same "No such file or directory"

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* your program is cutting out the colons? Also, make sure your program has rights to open the other directories.

Comment: You should make sure the directories in the PATH variable are separated, not added together. Look at the edit to the answer.

Comment: Good to know! Please consider marking this answer as the solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Think delimiter "/:" you chose wasn't token'izing the PATH variable as expected. I changed it to ":" and I am getting every entry in path properly delimited:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char pwd[4096]="", *limit=":";
    char *p = NULL;
    strcpy (pwd, getenv("PATH"));

    p = strtok (pwd, limit);
    printf ("%s\n", p);

    while (p != NULL){
        p = strtok(NULL,limit);
        printf ("%s\n", p); 
        }
return (0); 
}
```

> Output: /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin ...
>
> Not sure if that's what you want.